# How do I naturally sort an array of multi-dot numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, natural-sort

Want to sort an array like this:

`arr = ['4.1.5', '4.1.1', '4.1.2', '10.1']`

Expected:

`['4.1.1', '4.1.2', '4.1.5', '10.1']`

Got:

`["10.1", "4.1.1", "4.1.2", "4.1.5"]`

What I've tried:

`arr.sort(&:to_i)` and `arr.sort(&:to_f)` but none of them handle the double dots

Comment: Or you can use a third party library, e.g. [this](https://github.com/github/version_sorter).

Comment: The answers in the other question are a bit more complex, here is a simpler solution for this problem.

arr.sort_by {|e| e.split('.').map(&:to_i)}

Comment: `arr.sort_by { |v| Gem::Version.new(v) }` is not too complex